# Proper way to add event listener to angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to add event listener to angular, but it looks like my listener is not working properly, callback is called once on directive initialization and then isn't working, code for directive looks like this:

```
var someDir = function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'someTmpl',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.someFunc = function () { console.log('called'); };

            console.log(element[0].getElementsByClassName('some-elm'));
            element[0].getElementsByClassName('some-elm')[0].addEventListener('mousedown', scope.someFunc());
        }
    }
};
```

And on page load in console I can see:

```
[input.some-elm.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid]
called
```

So, what can be a reason for such unexpected behaviour and what is a proper  way to add event listener to angular directive?

P.S.: This directive is inside ui-view, can such behaviour have something to do with it?

Comment: You need pass reference to `addEventListener`. Try this `element[0].getElementsByClassName('some-elm')[0].addEventListener('mousedown', scope.someFunc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ngMousedown in html template on '.some-elm' directly.

Read more: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMousedown

Answer (score 1):

In the link function,you get element on which directive is placed.

You can use [`bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) method to attach event.

```
link: function(scope, element) {
    var someFunc = function() { console.log('called'); };

    element.bind('mousedown',someFunc);
}
```

If you want to expose the `someFunc` to template mapped to directive within the `link function`,

then you can do it as  `scope.someFunc =someFunc`